# Data Densification Oracle query not efficient and slowly

Tags: performance, oracle, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to cope with data densification for reporting purposes. I created two dimension tables (time & skills) and one data table (calls). Now since during certain time there are no calls in the data table, I will not get a time series including all the days. I now have studied many samples in the Internet how to cope with data densification and came up the the solution below.

Query works as intended, just it takes quite long and I have the feeling it is quite inefficient. Could you please advice me how to speed up query execution time?

Thank you and best regards,
Alex

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DAY_ID,
  DAY_SHORT,
  WEEK_ID,
  MONTH_ID,
  QUARTER_ID,
  YEAR_ID,
  AREA,
  FIRMA,
  PRODUCT,
  PRODUCT_FAMILY,
  PRODUCT_WFM,
  LANGUAGE,
  NVL(NCO,0) NCO,
  NVL(NCH,0) NCH,
  NVL(NCH60,0) NCH60,
  NVL(LOST,0) LOST
FROM (
  SELECT
    DS.AREA,
    DS.FIRMA,
    DS.PRODUCT,
    DS.PRODUCT_FAMILY,
    DS.PRODUCT_WFM,
    DS.LANGUAGE,
    SUM(NVL(CH.HANDLED,0)+NVL(CH.LOST,0)) AS NCO,
    SUM(CH.HANDLED) AS NCH,
    SUM(CH.HANDLED_IN_SL) AS NCH60,
    SUM(CH.LOST) AS LOST,
    CH.DELIVER_DATE,
    CH.SKILL_NAME
  FROM
    WFM.WFM_TBL_DIMENSION_SKILL DS
  LEFT JOIN
    OPS.VW_CALL_HISTORY CH
  ON
    DS.SPLIT_NAME=CH.SKILL_NAME
  GROUP BY
    DS.AREA,
    DS.FIRMA,
    DS.PRODUCT,
    DS.PRODUCT_FAMILY,
    DS.PRODUCT_WFM,
    DS.LANGUAGE,
    CH.DELIVER_DATE,
    CH.SKILL_NAME
) temp_values
PARTITION BY
(
  temp_values.AREA,
  temp_values.FIRMA,
  temp_values.PRODUCT,
  temp_values.PRODUCT_FAMILY,
  temp_values.PRODUCT_WFM,
  temp_values.LANGUAGE,
  temp_values.DELIVER_DATE,
  temp_values.SKILL_NAME
)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
    DAY_ID,
    DAY_SHORT,
    WEEK_ID,
    MONTH_ID,
    QUARTER_ID,
    YEAR_ID
  FROM
    WFM.WFM_TBL_DIMENSION_TIME
  WHERE
    DAY_ID BETWEEN(SELECT MIN(DELIVER_DATE) FROM OPS.VW_CALL_HISTORY) and TRUNC(sysdate-1)
) temp_time
ON
  temp_values.DELIVER_DATE=temp_time.DAY_ID
```

Comment: well what about cardinalities and indexes?

Comment: While you're at it, how about the output from EXPLAIN PLAN?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to the EXPLAIN PLAN and I will not get it. Don't ask me why :)  I'm now trying how much indexing will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the execution plan and check which steps take very long. Use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to get it. Look for full table scans, see if indexes could help. Make sure you have up-to-date stats on the tables.
Since you are talking about dimension tables, this code is assumed to be from a data warehousing database. If it is, do you use partitions? Parallel DML? Are you using EE?

Comment: You should consider using table aliases in your query. Obviously, it will not impact performance, but will improve readability and ease code maintenance.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have access to the EXPLAIN PLAN and I will not get it. Don't ask me why :) Parallel DML already reduced query execution time by 20%. Thanks for this hint.

I'm now trying how much indexing will help.

I have some gut feeling that PARTITION BY () over many arguments generates unnecessary data. For this reason I had to use SELECT DISTINCT in order to ignore multiple entries that are equal. Is there any other possibility to reduce argument size in PARTITION BY?

Comment: As far as I know, you do not need "access" to `EXPLAIN PLAN`; it should be available. You might need to create an output table (`PLAN_TABLE`) of your own, but even this seems to be unlikely as the default output table (`PLAN_TABLE$`) is accessible to `PUBLIC` (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) and via the `PLAN_TABLE` synonym. Try something simple as `EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'test' FOR SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;` and then query `PLAN_TABLE`.

Comment: And if you really do not have access or any required privilege needed for `EXPLAIN PLAN` then demand it. You are developer, it is a must in your position. Actually, demand `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`. (I assume you are not using a production system...)

Comment: Thank you Szilard, I now asked for permittion SELECT ANY DICTIONARY. You are right, it is not a production system but a Data Mart. I will come back with the execution plan once permittion is granted. Rgds

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the arguments in `PARTITION BY ()`  to a single primary key (temp_values.SKILL_NAME) and joined the missing information from the skill dimension with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` at the end of the above described query. In that way no more equal duplications are produced which leds me reduce `SELECT DISTINCT to SELECT`.

Additionally I added foreign & primary keys and let the query run in parallel mode.

It helps me to reduce execution time by over 80%, which is sufficient. Thanks guys!